# Adding switch to domain, do I need to use vlan

Tags: switch, vlan

I have a windows 2016 server. I am setting up a domain on it (office.local), and user accounts through Active Directory. Do I need a managed switch and vlan to allow PCs to connect to the server, or if I just plug the server and PCs into any swithc will it work?

Since the server is handling DHCP, I think it should work with a dumb switch.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your PC has a single NIC with a single IP, you do not need a managed switch nor VLANs.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need a managed switch and vlan to allow PCs to connect to the server, or if I just plug the server and PCs into any swithc will it work?

If you simply just need them to connect, pretty much any switch should work. You don't need a managed switch or vlans to get started.